# using require_once() with files outside of the site root

Tags: php, path, require-once

I have an application that is broken up into several sites with common files. The structure looks like this...

```
|
|--[Site A] <--Web site A points here
|   |-- (Files and folders)
|
|--[Site B] <--Web site B points here
|   |-- (Files and folders)
|
|--[Includes] <--common files are here
```

If I am in Site A or B and I do something like this:

```
require_once(include.php)
```

everything works fine, but if I do this:

```
require_once(../Includes/include.php)
```

I get an error.

I am getting around that by doing some legwork to parse the path, such as

```
$path = explode( "\\" , __DIR__ );
for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) { array_pop( $path ); }
$path = implode( "\\" , $path ) . "\\includes\\initialize.php" ;
```

While this works, I am looking for a more elegant solution using require_once()

thanks.

Comment: `require_once(../Includes/include.php)` -- are the missing quotes a typo or is that what the real code looks like?

Comment: This has been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370053/how-to-include-file-outside-document-root

Answer (score 1):

are you sure the script that contains "require_once" is in [Site A] and not in a subfolder of it? I'm asking because path is relative to the including script. for example, if you have an Index.php file in site A that includes "/subfolder/config.php" and you want config.php include something outside site A, you would have to use

```
require_once(../../Includes/include.php)
```