# FourSquare: Where should I store my client secret?

Tags: foursquare

Some said:

(Since PHP deals with the local file system it is actually preferable to relocate your secrets.php to a location outside of the web server path. Just in case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would mean you store your secrets.php file 'above the root'. Meaning it's not accessible through a browser, but could be included via a php `include()`.

This [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370053/how-to-include-file-outside-document-root) explains this in more detail.