# linking to files above the root PHP

Tags: php, download, webserver, hosting

I recently switched servers.  From shared w/ control panel to a VPS

On my old server this PHP worked:

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= 'welcome.doc'");
header('Content-type: application/msword');
readfile("/home/abcme/aboveroot/admin/welcome.doc");
```

The same folder structure exists in the new serve. There is a folder above home named aboveroot and a folder in that called admin and a file in that called welcome.doc

I changed the /home/abcme so that "abcme" is the correct new accountname

Now I get an error saying the file cannot be found.  Is there something that needs to be enabled in my server or what else might explain this?

Comment: directory or file permission error i would guess.

Comment: If it's above home wouldn't the path be `/aboveroot/admin/welcome.doc`?

Comment: This might be a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370053/how-to-include-file-outside-document-root).

Comment: You could use getcwd() to get the path where you have the script and check if the file structure is ok, then correct the path.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said the structure would be like so:

```
>aboveroot 
  -home
  -admin
    -welcome.doc
```

So your header would say (assuming that /aboveroot is your webroot, which doesn't seem the case given the name):

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= 'welcome.doc'");
header('Content-type: application/msword');
readfile("/aboveroot/admin/welcome.doc");
```